# PHP plus/minus button does not work properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a cart page, and there is a plus minus button for quantity with each item on the page.

When i click on the first items plus/minus button it works fine but when i click on the second items buttons, then buttons works and it changes the quantity on the first items quantity input and does not update quantity either for the 1st or the second item but changes the number only.

[image]

**CODE**

```
<iframe name="quantity" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<form action="checkout_qty_update.php" method="post" target="quantity">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prITTD; ?>" name="hiddenID">
<input style="font-size:21px;" type="submit" value="-" onclick='javascript: subtractQty();' class="minus">
<input id="number" type="number" value="<?php echo $qtyT; ?>" class="qty" name="picpac"/>
<input style="font-size:21px;" type="submit" value="+"  onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("number").value++;' class="plus">
</form>
```

**JS for plus/minus**

```
function subtractQty(){
    if(document.getElementById("number").value - 1 < 1)
return;
    else
 document.getElementById("number").value--;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's because all your inputs type number have the same ID `number `

Comment: @Robiseb I tried as u r saying its not working, please you tell me how to put that unique id for each. I tried by putting `"number<?php echo $prITTD; ?>"`

Comment: That's correct. I believe those items are created diamically and you can not give them an id, because this will be always the same. you need to use a class for the items. Additionally you can better use some `jquery` to do what you want.

Comment: @Franco would you please tell me how or create according to my code?

Comment: What have you tried to debug your code? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase Quite an old question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's because all your inputs type number have the same ID `number`.

Try changing your HTML code like this

```
<form action="checkout_qty_update.php" method="post" target="quantity">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prITTD; ?>" name="hiddenID">
  <input [...] onclick="javascript: subtractQty('<?php echo $prITTD; ?>');" >
  <input [...] id="number_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>" />
  <input [...] onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('number_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>').value++;">
</form>
```

And your JS code

```
function subtractQty(prITTD){
  var pr = document.getElementById("number_" + prITTD);
  if (pr.value - 1 < 1)
    return;
  else
    pr.value--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to work plus and minus button that auto calculate price:

```
function cartElement($productimg, $productname, $productColor, $productprice, $productid){
$element = "

<form action=\"cart.php?action=remove&id=$productid\" method=\"post\" class=\"cart-items\">
                <div class=\"border rounded\">
                    <div class=\"row bg-white\">
                        <div class=\"col-md-3 pl-0\">
                            <img src=$productimg alt=\"Image1\" class=\"img-fluid\">
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                            <h5 class=\"pt-2\">$productname</h5>
                            <small class=\"pt-2\">$productColor</small>
                            <h5 class=\"pt-2\">$$productprice</h5>
                            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-warning\">Save for Later</button>
                            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger mx-2\" name=\"remove\">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"col-md-3 py-5\">
                            <div>
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn bg-light border rounded-circle\"><i class=\"fas fa-minus\"></i></button>
                                <input type=\"text\" value=\"1\" class=\"form-control w-25 d-inline\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn bg-light border rounded-circle\"><i class=\"fas fa-plus\"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

";
echo  $element;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it